# Queue of data when sending Google Firebase commands

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp32

sorry if my English is messy :(

Recently, I learned about the IoT system and started implementing it in several simple projects.
Well, one of my projects uses Esp32 wifi and 16 channel Relay to control lights via Firebase. However, there is a delay in the process, because the system (Looping) always checks one by one in the database.

For example, I update the Relay 6 command to turn on. Then the order must be queued up until it is your turn to turn on.

If 1 relay = 1 second, it will take 16 seconds for each command, because the system always starts from scratch. Not to mention if the network is slow, sometimes it's almost a minute of waiting

how to avoid queuing when sending commands?

Thank you  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHQQQ.jpg)

Comment: Copy and post your code into your question, not posting your code as an image.